# XCode 6.1crash on run project

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, osx-yosemite

I upgraded XCode to versin 6.1 (6A1052d) and now my project crash when i try to run it on simulator.
Doesn't happen all times. The pattern seams to be after i made code changes.
No exception is throw, the XCode just restart as nothing happened.

It's running on Yosemite 10.10.

I already try:

- change the computer language to english U.S and region to U.S, which was recommended to fix a similar problem in a early version.
- recreated the project. Project has both Swift and objective-c, shouldn't matter but anyway...
- find info on xcode logs. No logs are generated at library\logs when this happens. Any place where i can find xcode logs?

This is odd, i don't believe that xCode release its so buggy that don't run properly, so must be something less usual in settings or in project that testers missed, but have no clue of what.

Comment: Find out that after a clean always run the project successfully.

Comment: Found out other thing. Its not a crash, it simple closes the workspace. Found out trying to run when still building. An message box pops asking if i want to close the workspace while the project is still building.

Answer (score 1):

fwiw, I found that this issue doesn't happen if I use the cmd-R hotkey instead of clicking the Play button.

I can also verify that this isn't a crash.  It's as if the Close Workspace command is being invoked at the wrong time.  Definitely a defect though.

I'm on Yosemite 10.10.1 running the latest Xcode 6.1.1.  The project was upgraded from Xcode 5.1.1 where it continues to work fine.  Not using Swift.  US English.  Pretty standard install.